# How to create a DStream from a List of string?

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, dstream

I have a list of string, but i cant find a way to change the list to a DStream of spark streaming.
I tried this:

```
val tmpList = List("hi", "hello")    
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(tmpList))   
val rowRdd = rdd.map(v => Row(v: _*))
```

But the eclipse says sparkContext is not a member of sqlContext, so, How can i do this?
Appreciate your help, Please.

Answer (score 3):

DStream is the sequence of RDD and it is created when you have register a received to some streaming source like Kafka. For testing if you want to create DStream from list of RDD's you can do that as follows:

```
val rdd1 = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(tmpList))
val rdd2 = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(tmpList1))
ssc.queueStream[String](mutable.Queue(rdd1,rdd2))
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am pretty new with spark, i do not really understand you answer. You said: create DStream from list of RDD. But how can i get a list of RDD with a list of String ,cause i am not sure the code i have writen in the question is write.

Comment: Thank you, i rewrite the code:val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(coutList)
    val resultInputStream = ssc.queueStream(scala.collection.mutable.Queue(rdd))
    val results  = resultInputStream.map(x=>x), Does the sqlContext is an object of class org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext? and whether the code i have written is write?

Comment: hi, cause the ssc is an object of StreamingContext :val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10)), so when i add  a val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf), there is a SparkException says only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM, so there maybe a interrupt between sparkContext and ssc, do you know why?